# Firebase handleIntent AbstractMethodError

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I receive a push notification on Android, I get the below error. I can't really seem to find any information about it. Can anyone help? I am really at a loss.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-1-thread-1 Process: com.mycompany.myerror, PID:
>   22712 java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void
>   com.google.firebase.iid.zzb.handleIntent(android.content.Intent)" at
>   com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$1.run(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    //https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**FirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        try {
            sendNotification(remoteMessage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    private void sendNotification(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) throws Exception {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
        String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());

        String contentTitle = "New Push Message";
        String contentText = "Received at " + strDate;

        Utilities.sendNotification(getApplicationContext(),
                getNotificationIcon(),
                contentTitle,
                contentText,
                0,
                HomeActivity.class,
                Utilities.getNotificationId(getApplicationContext()));

    }
```

**Utilities**

```
 public static void sendNotification(Context appContext,
                                            int icon,
                                            String title,
                                            String msg,
                                            long when,
                                            Class<? extends Context> classToLaunch,
                                            long processId) {

            //Define notification msg
            Intent launchIntent = null;

            if (classToLaunch != null) {
                launchIntent = new Intent(appContext, classToLaunch);
            } else {
                launchIntent = new Intent();
            }

            // This is dummy data for just differentiate Pending intent
            // only set value that is check IntentFilter
            launchIntent.addCategory("CATEGORY" + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            launchIntent.addFlags((int) System.currentTimeMillis());
            launchIntent.setAction("ACTION" + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

            // also make launch mode to singleTop in manifest for that activity
            launchIntent.setFlags(
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // intent to be launched when click on notification
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(appContext,
                    0,
                    launchIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            //Instantiate the notification
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(appContext); //(icon, msg, when);
            builder.setContentTitle(title);
            builder.setSmallIcon(icon);
            builder.setWhen(when);
            builder.setTicker(msg);
            builder.setContentText(msg);
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            builder.setAutoCancel(true);
            builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS);
            builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);


            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) appContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify((int) processId, builder.build());
        }
```

**HomeActivity**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
                Object value = getIntent().getExtras().get(key);
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG_APPLICATION) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You should keep the Firebase libraties version and Google play services libraries similar. So update the version numbers of the Firebase libararies to 10.2.1:

Change:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
```

To:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
```

Comment: @user-44651 Is this answer your question?

Comment: This worked for me when I had one lib depending on com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0 and one on com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1. Adding the dependency to messaging:10.2.1 resolved my issue here.

Comment: all library versions under similar packages should match, please accept this as correct answer

Answer (score 13):

Yout must have every the google play service's line in tha same version

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
```

Comment: Don't ask me why... It even solved some stubborn compilation puzzler. handleIntent was missing at all. Strange because on 10 it should be defined, on 11 it should be defined... not typical for them to break compilation compatibility, and yet... facts speak.

Answer (score 1):

I just cleaned the project and it worked