# Firebase onMessageReceived is crashing the application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Does anyone faced with the similar problem before? Whenever I send message, app is crashing immediately. Here is my MessageReceiver class:

```
public class MessageReceiver extends FirebaseMessagingService {
        final String TAG = "MessageReceiver";
        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

            Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: "+remoteMessage.getFrom());

            if(remoteMessage.getData().size() >0){
                Log.d(TAG,"payload: "+remoteMessage.getData());
            }
        }
    }
```

I even tried with empty method onMessageReceived still crushing the app.

This is the version that Im compiling:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
```

This is the json that Im sending to app through PostMan:

```
{
    "to":"d55nTfZR5-A:APA91bFW88heY4Hoh34...",
    "data":{
        "message":"hello"
    }
}
```

[image: LogCat:]

Comment: The versions of your Firebase and Google Play Services must be identical.  See this related question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097293/firebase-handleintent-abstractmethoderror.  If the problem persists, post your app module build.gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out. If anyone face with the similar problem in the feature you need to make sure that you also compile firebase-core along firebase-messaging and that you match the same version with google play services.

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
```

After this everything worked fine. Thanks @FnR for your suggestions.

**Edit 9th June 2022**

This are the current most latest versions:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.5'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.0.0'
```

Also want to mention that it is a good practice to use now Firebase Android BoM (Bill of materials) to manage your Firebase dependencies, where the versions will be taken care of for you.
Example:

```
dependencies {
      // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
      implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.1.0')
    
      // Declare the dependencies for the desired Firebase products without specifying versions
      // For example, declare the dependencies for Firebase Authentication and Cloud Firestore
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
    }
```

The above snippet is from Firebase docs, please for more info see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/learn-more

Comment: May I please suggest you editing `compile` to be `implementation` to work with newer Gradle versions? And mention that it is `app/build.gradle` where this goes?

Comment: @Karatekid430 just updated the above answer - hope you find it helpful. Thanks for the suggestions!